# Horizontal Collection View Error While Selecting Items

Tags: xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios

I am facing issue in CollectionView while clicking data in collection view.
I'm selecting a middle of data but it goes to a first itself. And I'm facing this issue in iOS.

```
 <CollectionView 
                x:Name="rooms_List"
                IsEnabled="True"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRoom}"
                SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding Source={x:Reference ThePage}, Path= BindingContext.RoomChanged}"
                ItemsLayout = "HorizontalList"
                SelectionChanged="RoomCollectionSelectionChanged"
                BackgroundColor = "white"
                HeightRequest="50"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                ItemsSource="{Binding RoomList}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid>
                            <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,15">
                                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Label  Text ="{Binding RoomName}"  Padding="20,10,20,0" />
                                    <BoxView x:Name="line" HeightRequest="3" IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected}" BackgroundColor="#1484B8" WidthRequest="5" Margin="18,0,15,0" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </StackLayout>
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

This is the code am using so far. In Android it works fine. I'm facing this issue in iOS only.

[image]

My RoomCollectionSelectionChanged Event

```
private void RoomCollectionSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CurrentSelection.Count == 0)
            {
                room_image.IsVisible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                var selectedItem = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Room;
                selectedRoom = selectedItem.RoomName;
                if (selectedRoom == "All")
                {
                    room_image.IsVisible = false;
                }
                else if (e.PreviousSelection.Count == 1)
                {
                    var previousItem = (e.PreviousSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Room)?.RoomName;
                    if (previousItem != "")
                    {
                        room_image.IsVisible = true;
                        room_image.Source = selectedItem.RoomImage;
                    }
                }
                else
                { 
                    room_image.IsVisible = true;
                    room_image.Source = selectedItem.RoomImage;
                }
            }
        }
```

ViewModel - SelectedRoomEvent

```
 private void SelectedRoomEvent()
        {
            if (SelectedRoom != null)
            {
                string RoomName = SelectedRoom.RoomName;
                if (RoomName.Equals("All"))
                {
                    GetDeviceAndRoomData();
                }
                else
                {
                    int RoomId = SelectedRoom.RoomId;
                    RoomList.Clear();
                    var rooms = db.GetRoomAsync().Result.ToList();
                    roomList.Add(new Room
                    {
                        Id = 0,
                        RoomId = 0,
                        RoomName = "All",
                        RoomImage = "none",
                        IsSelected = false
                    });
                    foreach (var room in rooms)
                    {
                        Room r = new Room();
                        r.Id = room.Id;
                        r.RoomId = room.RoomId;
                        r.RoomName = room.RoomName;
                        r.RoomImage = room.RoomImage;
                        r.IsSelected = (r.RoomName == RoomName) ? true : false;
                        RoomList.Add(r);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {

            }
        }
```

---

**UPDATE**

The List bounces back to beginning while selecting the Item, because in ViewModel -> SelectedEvent(), List is cleared and created again, to show the Blue Underline for Selected item. How do this without clearing List?

Comment: I removed my answer , mistake the question . Look here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69824356/scroll-to-selected-item-of-collection-view-in-ios-in-xamarin-forms

Comment: You haven't provided all your code. Please provide your ViewModel so we can understand the business logic that is being represented by the view.

Comment: What example code did you base this on? Can you provide a link? Also, need to see source code for `RoomCollectionSelectionChanged` method.

Comment: @AndrewH Hi I added a my all codes - ViewModel and CodeBehind. Kindly help

Comment: Run the repo I provided - see it work. `SelectRoom` clears the underline from the old item, and puts it on the new item. Is that what you need?

Comment: Yes @ToolmakerSteve its works partially for me. The Underline is coming after the few Seconds. The Refresh is not happening in my code exactly.

Comment: @ToolmakerSteve I Posted a Question Kindly suggest https://stackoverflow.com/q/70396439/17692337

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is minimal code, that scrolls Horizontal CollectionView correctly on both iOS and Android.

Please start from this code. Then add your code to it. If your code still has the symptom, then comment out lines of your code until you find what "breaks" the scrolling. Update code in question with the code you are using, and state which line(s) lead to the symptom.

[github repo here](https://github.com/ToolmakerSteve/XFIOSHorizCollViewScrollBug).

MainPage.xaml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:ios="clr-namespace:Xamarin.Forms.PlatformConfiguration.iOSSpecific;assembly=Xamarin.Forms.Core"
             ios:Page.UseSafeArea="true"
             x:Class="XFIOSHorizCollViewScrollBug.MainPage">

    <StackLayout>
        <!--SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding Source={x:Reference ThePage}, Path= BindingContext.RoomChanged}"-->
        <CollectionView 
                    x:Name="rooms_List" ItemsLayout = "HorizontalList" ItemsSource="{Binding RoomList}"
                    SelectionChanged="RoomCollectionSelectionChanged" HeightRequest="50"
                    SelectionMode="Single" HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never" >
            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid>
                        <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,0,15">
                            <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" Orientation="Vertical">
                                <Label  Text ="{Binding RoomName}"  Padding="20,10,20,0" />
                                <BoxView x:Name="line" HeightRequest="3" IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected}" BackgroundColor="#1484B8" WidthRequest="5" Margin="18,0,15,0" />
                            </StackLayout>
                        </StackLayout>
                    </Grid>
                </DataTemplate>
            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        </CollectionView>
    </StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

MainPage.xaml.cs:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XFIOSHorizCollViewScrollBug
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitRoomList();
            BindingContext = this;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Room> RoomList { get; set; }

        private Room _previousSelection;

        private void RoomCollectionSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var selectedItem = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Room;
            SelectRoom(selectedItem);
        }

        private void SelectRoom(Room room)
        {
            if (room != null) {
                if (_previousSelection != null)
                    _previousSelection.IsSelected = false;

                room.IsSelected = true;
                rooms_List.ScrollTo(room, position: ScrollToPosition.Center, animate: false);

                _previousSelection = room;
            }
        }

        string[] roomNames = new string[] {
            "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"
        };

        private void InitRoomList()
        {
            var rooms = new ObservableCollection<Room>();
            foreach (var name in roomNames) {
                rooms.Add(new Room(name));
            }

            var room = rooms[0];
            room.IsSelected = true;
            _previousSelection = room;

            RoomList = rooms;
        }
    }
}
```

Room.cs:

```
namespace XFIOSHorizCollViewScrollBug
{
    public class Room : Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject
    {
        public string RoomName { get; set; }

        public bool IsSelected {
            get => _isSelected;
            set {
                _isSelected = value;
                OnPropertyChanged();
            }
        }
        private bool _isSelected;

        public Room(string name, bool isSelected = false)
        {
            RoomName = name;
            IsSelected = isSelected;
        }
    }
}
```