# Collection View Refreshing issue While Selecting Item in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, collectionview

I have implemented horizontal list using **collection view** in Xamarin forms. The Underline doesn't come properly it will be late while selecting Item. The Refreshing is too late. AS you can see in the following Video

My Xaml Code

```
  <CollectionView
                x:Name="rooms_List"
                IsEnabled="True"
                SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRoom}"
                SelectionChangedCommand="{Binding Source={x:Reference ThePage}, Path= BindingContext.RoomChanged}"
                ItemsLayout = "HorizontalList"
                SelectionChanged="RoomCollectionSelectionChanged"
                BackgroundColor = "white"
                HeightRequest="50"
                SelectionMode="Single"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                ItemsSource="{Binding RoomList}">
                <CollectionView.ItemTemplate >
                    <DataTemplate>
                            <Grid>
                                <StackLayout VerticalOptions="Start" Orientation="Vertical">
                                    <Label  Text ="{Binding RoomName}"  Padding="20,10,20,0" />
                                    <BoxView x:Name="line" HeightRequest="3" IsVisible="{Binding IsSelected}" BackgroundColor="#1484B8" WidthRequest="5" Margin="18,0,15,0" />
                                </StackLayout>
                            </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
            </CollectionView>
```

My Xaml.cs **RoomCollectionSelectionChanged**

```
 private void RoomCollectionSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.CurrentSelection.Count == 0)
            {
                room_image.IsVisible = true;
            }
            else
            {
                var selectedItem = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Room;
                selectedRoom = selectedItem.RoomName;
                if (selectedRoom == "All")
                {
                    room_image.IsVisible = false;
                }
                else if (e.PreviousSelection.Count == 1)
                {
                    var previousItem = (e.PreviousSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Room)?.RoomName;
                    if (previousItem != "")
                    {
                        room_image.IsVisible = true;
                        room_image.Source = selectedItem.RoomImage;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    room_image.IsVisible = true;
                    room_image.Source = selectedItem.RoomImage;
                }
            }
        }
```

My ViewModel

```
private ObservableCollection<Room> roomList { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<Room> RoomList
        {
            get { return roomList; }
            set
            {
                roomList = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(RoomList));
            }
        }

        private Room selectedRoom { get; set; }

        public Room SelectedRoom
        {
            get { return selectedRoom; }
            set
            {
                selectedRoom = value;
            }
        }

        public bool isSelected { get; set; }

        public bool IsSelected
        {
            get { return isSelected; }
            set
            {
                if (value != isSelected)
                {
                    isSelected = value;
                    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(IsSelected));
                }
            }
        }

        private Room previousSelectedRoom;

        private void SelectedRoomEvent()
        {
            if (SelectedRoom != null)
            {
                DevicePage.checkRoom = true;
                string RoomName = SelectedRoom.RoomName;

                if (RoomName.Equals("All"))
                {
                    GetDeviceAndRoomData();
                }
                else
                {
                    int RoomId = SelectedRoom.RoomId;

                    if (previousSelectedRoom != null)
                    {
                        previousSelectedRoom.IsSelected = false;
                    }
                    previousSelectedRoom = SelectedRoom;
                    previousSelectedRoom.IsSelected = true;

                }
        }
```

My Model

```
public class Room
    {
        [PrimaryKey, AutoIncrement]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("roomId")]
        public int RoomId { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("serialNumber")]
        public string SerialNumber { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("roomName")]
        public string RoomName { get; set; }
        [JsonProperty("roomImage")]
        public string RoomImage { get; set; }
        [JsonIgnore]
        public bool IsSelected { get; set; }
    }
```

Please give suggestions how to fix this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmC20.gif)

Comment: When the selected item changes,  why do you let your CollectionView fire both events(`SelectionChangedCommand`  and `SelectionChanged`) at the same time?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Thanks for your comments
In SelectionChangedCommand am getting a list of Devices and in SelectionChanged am getting a list of rooms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see you use `e. PreviousSelection`  in your code. That is better than what I was doing in my repository, so I have modified [github ToolmakerSteve - repo XFIOSHorizCollViewScrollBug](https://github.com/ToolmakerSteve/XFIOSHorizCollViewScrollBug) to use that.

I made changes in several places in this file:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;
using System.Linq;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace XFIOSHorizCollViewScrollBug
{
    public partial class MainPage : ContentPage
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            InitRoomList();
            BindingContext = this;

            // After set BindingContext, so RoomCollectionSelectionChanged gets called.
            var room = RoomList[0];
            rooms_List.SelectedItem = room;
        }

        public ObservableCollection<Room> RoomList { get; set; }

        private void RoomCollectionSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var previousItem = e.PreviousSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Room;
            DeselectRoom(previousItem);
            var selectedItem = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Room;
            SelectRoom(selectedItem);
        }

        private void DeselectRoom(Room room)
        {
            if (room != null)
            {
                room.IsSelected = false;
            }
        }

        private void SelectRoom(Room room)
        {
            if (room != null) {
                room.IsSelected = true;
                rooms_List.ScrollTo(room, position: ScrollToPosition.Center, animate: false);
            }
        }

        string[] roomNames = new string[] {
            "One", "Two", "Three", "Four", "Five", "Six", "Seven", "Eight"
        };

        private void InitRoomList()
        {
            var rooms = new ObservableCollection<Room>();
            foreach (var name in roomNames) {
                rooms.Add(new Room(name));
            }

            RoomList = rooms;
        }
    }
}
```

The other files are the same as in [my answer to your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70385322/199364).

Please download my repository, build and run it, verify that it works. The change to underline happens INSTANTLY - as soon as you click on an item.

Then compare that to your code. Change your code until it matches what the working repo does.